# Remove corner of image with css

Tags: css

I'm looking to remove the corner of an image using CSS. I currently achieved this by adjusting the image, but I would rather learn how to do this properly.

Here is the page with the image shopped to what I wanted to achieve. The idea is to use the full image with CSS doing the snipping of the corner

http://goos3d.ie/home-2/

Comment: This page has several images..which one? Also do you mean removing the spacing surrouding an image instead of corner of an image?

Comment: Sorry, it's the main astronaut image. As you can see, the corner has been removed to emphasize the CTA. If you could imagine that image was still complete, I'm looking to replicate the removal of the corner, but with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few option to archive this effect:

**Clip Path**

Use CSS `clip-path` to cutt of the edges. This technique works like a mask in Photoshop. Unfortunately this property is relatively new and needs to be shimed in older browsers

**Image Mask**

You could create another image which works as mask and place it on top of your image:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="path/to/mask.svg" alt="" class="image-mask">
    <img src="path/to/image" alt="">
</div>

.image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-mask {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

**DIV Elements**

Use for `DIV` elements to create a corner and position them on top of you image:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="image-corner image-corner-top-left"></div>
    <div class="image-corner image-corner-top-right"></div>
    <div class="image-corner image-corner-bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="image-corner image-corner-bottom-right"></div>
    <img src="path/to/image" alt="">
</div>

.image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-corner {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    heigth: CORNER_HEIGHT;
    position: absolute;
    width: CORNER_WIDTH;
}

.image-corner-top-left {
    background-image: url('/path/to/corner-top-left');
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.image-corner-top-right {
    background-image: url('/path/to/corner-top-right');
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.image-corner-bottom-left {
    background-image: url('/path/to/corner-bottom-left');
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.image-corner-bottom-right {
    background-image: url('/path/to/corner-bottom-right');
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The astronaut picture that you are seeing does not involve any clipping of the image..The image is still there but parts of the image is hidden using css rules

Take a look at the image from the source url..Yes it is still there but parts of it is hidden on the website

[image]

Now you can simply replicate this behaviour using css 
to get some "clipping" with using css only

Add a background image to a div `background:url("....")`

Postion the image using `background-position` rule

See snippet below

```css
#astro {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid;
  background: url("http://goos3d.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/goos3d-moon-large2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: -400px 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="astro"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all it's not what the OP wanted, secondly the comma is not needed there.

Comment: My mistake with the comma..I believe the OP is trying to replicate the css rules that was found on the site he provided...I focused on this ***Here is the page with the image shopped to what I wanted to achieve.***

Comment: sorry, yes the image I provided in my example was the goal. I wasn't able to achieve it using CSS myself so I instead used photoshop to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy steps:

**First** You need to apply the following styling to the container `<div>` that has the background image:

```
.vc_parallax-content-moving-fade
{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Second** *The orange button will be hidden because of the above styling*, so you need to put the orange button immediately before the container that has the background image.

Then give it the following styling:

```
.vc_btn3
{
    z-index: 9999;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
}
```

Comment: `z-index: 2` is enough.

Comment: @K.Daniek, I know, just in case :)

Comment: great guys, thanks. I look forward to trying this out.